# How to integrate PHPExcel in Yii2 Framework?

Tags: php, yii2, phpexcel

I want to capture html form fields data and save it in a .xlsx file. I looked around and found PHPExcel but couldn't figure out how to integrate it to Yii2. Can someone tell me how to integerate. I want to use something like this in my controller:

```
require('../PHPExcel.php');
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel;
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,  "Excel2007");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="file.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');`
```

Comment: Add PHPExcel to the project using composer. Then refers to it using @vendor prefix in require('@vendor/...') to reach specific package

Comment: there is yii2 extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-phpexcel/

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli worked. TY

Comment: @Code717 thanks yours worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add PHPExcel to the project using composer. Then refers to it using @vendor prefix in require('@vendor/...') to reach specific package

Answer (score 3):

in your code replace this line :

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel;
```

with this :

```
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
```

also edit `$objWriter` to this :

```
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```

and to understand the basic idea here is Example :

```
          $objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();

          $sheet=0;

          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheet);
          $foos = [
                    ['firstname'=>'Jane',
                    'lastname'=>'pat'],
                    ['firstname'=>'Jane',
                    'lastname'=>'Jones'],
                    ['firstname'=>'Jane',
                    'lastname'=>'Doe'],
            ];

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(20);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('xxx')                     
         ->setCellValue('A1', 'Firstname')
         ->setCellValue('B1', 'Lastname');

     $row=2;

            foreach ($foos as $foo) {  

                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row,$foo['firstname']); 
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$row,$foo['lastname']);
                $row++ ;
            }

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    $filename = "MyExcelReport_".date("d-m-Y-His").".xls";
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename .' ');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Not really what I asked but helps for sure. Upvoted, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Add phpexcel to your vendors directory by installing it using composer.Next use it like this `$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();`
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this module worked for me initially. but then I added Yii2 and spent a long time looking for a solution to the problem. for those who find this topic, as I did and also added Yii2 to Yii1, I will leave this solution.

for me first helped this.

```
            spl_autoload_unregister(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
            require_once Yii::app()->params['rootPath'] . '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
            spl_autoload_register(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
```

when i added Yii2 i changed

```
            spl_autoload_unregister(['Yii', 'autoload']);
            spl_autoload_unregister(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
            require_once Yii::app()->params['rootPath'] . '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
            spl_autoload_register(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
            spl_autoload_register(['Yii', 'autoload']);
```

next use as writed user7702308

```
      $objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
      ...
      $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```